# How to hide server requests in React

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react app with `create-react-app` and I am wanna make a GET request to my server. I don't want the user to see the url of the request. Is it possible to hide it?

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: No; any requests the client makes are visible, because that's how web browsers work. You could (attempt to) obfuscate it, but meh. You could also make it incrementally more difficult to track by going through a web socket, but it'll just be there in the dev console. Why do you want to hide it?

Comment: My server does an api request and I dont want people to send many requests

Comment: There are any number of ways to implement rate limiting, but ultimately on the client side you're limited to what browsers can do, and your users. On the browser side you can only superficially rate-limit if you have evil users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Every request from the browser will be visible through the network tab.